Hello! I wonder if they just stopped making an interim release of Ubuntu?
Where is the ubuntu interim release? I only see a new LTS Ubuntu at download on official website of Ubuntu desktop. Did they just stop making an interim release?

https://releases.ubuntu.com

At the time of this post, the last interim release of Ubuntu was 23.10 in October of 2023.  It is supported through June/July of 2024.  The latest release of Ubuntu at the time of this post is 24.04 which is an LTS release.
Interim releases are "non-LTS releases" and the main download site tends to advertise the latest release and LTS by default.
Yes, Interim releases are still built and developed, but LTS releases are the major releases that gather the most attention and long-term support.
The next Interim release will be 24.10 in October.
You can find all supported release ISOs, etc. on https://releases.ubuntu.com

Thank you so much for information!
Have a great day!
